# How to make a simple progress button that changes color

Tags: javascript, button, progress

I want to create something like the first example but instead it needs to change the color and the text to "downloaded".
https://tympanus.net/Development/ProgressButtonStyles/

I tried working with the files but there was just too much for a beginner learning javascript.Is there a simple way to make a progress bar ?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it on many ways, but, this is the simplest one i can remember, currently. It relies on CSS transition of width property, and minimal javascript.

```js
btn=document.getElementById('btn');
prog=document.getElementById('progress');
text=document.getElementById('text');
btn.onclick=function() {
prog.classList.add('anima');
prog.addEventListener("transitionend", function(event) {
  text.textContent="downloaded";
}, false);

}
```

```css
button {
  color:white;
  border:1px solid gray;
  border-radius:5px;
  background:green;
  cursor:pointer;
  width:200px;
  height:70px;
  padding:0;
  position:relative;
   outline:none;
}
#progress {
  width:0px;
  height:70px;
 background-color:darkgreen; /*set desired color*/
 position:absolute;
 left:0;
 top:0;
 z-index:2;
 border-radius:5px;


}
#progress.anima {
  width:200px;
  transition: width 2s ease; 
}
#bar {
  position:relative;
}
span {
  z-index:9;
  position:relative;
  text-transform:uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div id="bar">
<button id="btn">
<span id="text">SUBMIT</span>
</button>
<div id="progress">
</div>
</div>
```

So, set container, add button, add progress bar div, with initial width:0, set position:absolute, to cover button, place text above (higer z-index), add class 'anima' on click:

```
#progress.anima {
  width:200px;
  transition: width 2s ease; 
}
```

which will make smooth transition of width, add event listener on progress bar, which will listen for 'transitionend' event, and change text of span, when animation is finished.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout basic progress bars -- http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_progressbar.asp. I've also created a simple example that builds from the simple progress bar and shows how you can use javascript to increment the width. The progress bar includes a container as well as an overlay div that has its width adjusted acording to the progress. You can change the background colours of both the container and the progress bar itself.

```js
var progressBtn = document.getElementById('progress_btn');
var progressElement = document.getElementById('progress_bar');
var submitText = document.getElementById('submit_text');

progressBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  // Update the text.
  submitText.textContent = 'Downloading...';
  
  // Initialize the progress variable.
  var progress = 0;
  
  // Move the progress bar by 10% every second.
  var progressInterval = setInterval(function() {
   progress += 10;
    progressElement.style.width = progress + '%';
    
    // Clear the interval once we've reached 100%.
    if (progress == 100) {
   clearInterval(progressInterval);
    }
  }, 1000);
});
```

```css
.btn {
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: #5b92a1;
    border-radius: 2px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.progress {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #63b1b3;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 2px;
    transition: width 1s ease;
    width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="progress_btn" class="btn">
  <div id="progress_bar" class="progress"></div>
  <span id="submit_text">Submit</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var progress = document.getElementById('progress');

document.getElementById('accept').addEventListener('click', function() {
    if(progress.value < 100) progress.value += 5;
}, false);

document.getElementById('reject').addEventListener('click', function() {
    progress.value -= 5;
}, false);
```

```css
.progress {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  width: 450px;
  height: 35px;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
}
.progress::-webkit-progress-value {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, #f74c4a, #ea0d0a);
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #f74c4a, #ea0d0a);
}
.progress::-moz-progress-bar {
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #f74c4a, #ea0d0a);
}
.progress[value^="3"]:not([value="3"])::-webkit-progress-value, .progress[value^="4"]:not([value="4"])::-webkit-progress-value, .progress[value^="5"]:not([value="5"])::-webkit-progress-value {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, #ffd44b, #fec100);
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #ffd44b, #fec100);
}
.progress[value^="3"]:not([value="3"])::-moz-progress-bar, .progress[value^="4"]:not([value="4"])::-moz-progress-bar, .progress[value^="5"]:not([value="5"])::-moz-progress-bar {
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #ffd44b, #fec100);
}
.progress[value^="6"]:not([value="6"])::-webkit-progress-value, .progress[value^="7"]:not([value="7"])::-webkit-progress-value, .progress[value^="8"]:not([value="8"])::-webkit-progress-value, .progress[value^="9"]:not([value="9"])::-webkit-progress-value, .progress[value="100"]::-webkit-progress-value {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, #4fd364, #2bab3f);
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #4fd364, #2bab3f);
}
.progress[value^="6"]:not([value="6"])::-moz-progress-bar, .progress[value^="7"]:not([value="7"])::-moz-progress-bar, .progress[value^="8"]:not([value="8"])::-moz-progress-bar, .progress[value^="9"]:not([value="9"])::-moz-progress-bar, .progress[value="100"]::-moz-progress-bar {
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #4fd364, #2bab3f);
}
.progress:after {
  content: attr(value) "%";
  margin-left: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 2em;
}

.buttons {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.button {
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
      -ms-flex: 0 0 75px;
          flex: 0 0 75px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  border: 5px solid #fff;
}
.button.button-accept {
  background: #4fd364;
}
.button.button-reject {
  background: #f74c4a;
}
.button:first-child {
  margin-right: 25px;
}
.button:hover {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(1px) translateY(1px);
          transform: translateX(1px) translateY(1px);
}

.button-icon {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}

.progress-container {
  background: #fff;
  font: normal normal 16px -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", "Roboto", "Oxygen", "Ubuntu", "Cantarell", "Fira Sans", "Droid Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  border: 2px solid #eee;
  padding: 25px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.container {
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 25px;
}

svg {
  fill: currentColor;
}

body {
  background: #fff url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/316871/geometry_mint.png);
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="progress-container">
    <progress class="progress" id="progress" value="25" max="100"></progress>
  </div>
  <div class="buttons">
    <button class="button button-accept" id="accept">
      <svg class="button-icon" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
        <path d="M9 16.172l10.594-10.594 1.406 1.406-12 12-5.578-5.578 1.406-1.406z"></path>
      </svg>
    </button>
    <button class="button button-reject" id="reject">
      <svg class="button-icon" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
        <path d="M18.984 6.422l-5.578 5.578 5.578 5.578-1.406 1.406-5.578-5.578-5.578 5.578-1.406-1.406 5.578-5.578-5.578-5.578 1.406-1.406 5.578 5.578 5.578-5.578z"></path>
      </svg>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```